# How do you execute a script on destroy of a aws_instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, terraform

In terraform, there's a [Destroy Time provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/syntax#destroy-time-provisioners) but these execute locally or I have to use SSH which means I have to run it from a server that has an SSH key to the remote server.  Which also means if I protect with a bastion server I won't be able to do this operation.

The [Destroy Time provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/syntax#destroy-time-provisioners) also does not allow referencing another node so this does not work.

```
    connection {
      type = "ssh"
      user = var.docker_username
      host = aws_instance.managers[0].public_ip
    }
```

I was wondering if it can be done on its own without having to do an SSH connection.

I was thinking it can be done via [lamda lifecycle hook](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/tutorial-lifecycle-hook-lambda.html#lambda-add-lifecycle-hook%3F) not sure if it will work with EC2.

This is specifically for Docker Swarm where I want to execute `docker node update --availabilty drain` and `docker node rm` after 10 seconds.

Comment: This is intended for EKS, but there could be an equiv for docker swarm (although possibly not because swarm is a dead project): https://github.com/aws/aws-node-termination-handler

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I wonder if you can add a service script and when that 'service' stops, it uses the AWS cli/API to get the status of the VM. If the status is `shutting-down` it can execute whatever you need to run.